# How readonly entity get persisted for the first time

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

if readonly entity cannot be persisted , how it is persisted for the first time. thinking in the matter lead me to three choice for the persist of readonly entity:

1. readonly entity  included in two type of mapping at which it is
   not readyonly in one of those type.
2. readonly entity  inserted to database without the use of jpa.
3. legacy database

what i want to know is there any other choice? is the first choice legal at which part of users/system can insert readyonly entity (configuration for example) and the major part of users just read those entity?

Comment: Why do you want to know this ? Is there a problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: the question, is how to benefit from ready only entity, if you cannot persist it.

Comment: Simply to protect any thing to be written to database by mistake. Same as the concept of immutability.

Comment: why need to protect a thing that has no way to be inserted for the first time(protect something that will not be created) . do you understand my question in the first place @Shahzeb.

Comment: I'm not sure of your question because you have outlined all the answers anyway.  Read-only is for the cases where your application should never change the data.  Writable would be for other applications that might need to insert/update that data.   Think of employee data - one persistence unit might allow reading it, while another meant for an administrator app might allow an expanded view and modifying the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the first choice legal at which part of users/system can insert
>   readyonly entity (configuration for example) and the major part of
>   users just read those entity?

You can do what you need in your application, as there is no restriction on how many entities can map to the same table.  You would just have to adjust your cache usage to account for changes made in one entity not being shown or picked up by other entity caches until those entities are refreshed/reloaded.i.e.you need a way to cause the other users to see your configuration changes.  This holds true for different entities mapping to the same table data just as it would for multiple instances of the same JPA application though.